# When is the Fourier transform analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform

If we have a function $f(x)$ with Fourier transform $\tilde{f}(k)$, what properties of $f(x)$ ensure that $\tilde{f}(k)$ is analytic?

Comment: it's about decay. you want the fourier transform to decay exponentially at infinity to ensure analyticity on the real line. You want the transform to decay faster than any exponent to ensure the function is entire. Consider functions with compact support